# await async write smoothly to ui but still freeze it

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am doing an interpreter-ish. The UI is a WPF App. On a button click, I launch a long task that has to write to the ui. I have done similar things, in the past, with a background worker. I realised that the background worker is obsolete and async is the way to go ( less noisy & cleaner etc. ).

I've got my long task to smoothly write text to the screen while looping, but the screen is still 'frozen' i.e can't click on buttons etc.

If I add a sleep of 30 ms at the end of my task.run, the ui gets responsive and my object events are working. But the sleeps seems to make it much slower than 30 ms.

```
private void AnalyzeButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    var flowManager = new InterpreterFlowManager(){ ... }
    flowManager.Initialize();
    flowManager.ContinueFlow();
}
....

public class InterpreterFlowManager
{
    async public void ContinueFlow()
    {
        string LineBuffer = "";

        string lastTextBlockString = "";
        while (...)
        {
            lastTextBlockString = "";
            bool endLoop = false;

            await Task.Run(() => 
            {
                if (...)
                {
                    ...
                    if (...)
                    {
                        switch (...)
                        {
                            case x:
                                lastTextBlockString = "\r\nEntrer un nombre :";
                                endLoop = true;
                                break;
                            case y:
                                lastTextBlockString = "\r\n" + ConsoleInfo.Message;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    LineIndex++;

                          *********************************
                           SMALL SLEEP HERE MAKE UI RESPONSIVE.
                          ************************************
            });

            //ACCESS TO A UI TEXTBOX
            var lastTextBlock = (InteractiveWindow.Children.Cast<TextBox>().Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.IsReadOnly)).Last();
            //SUCESSFULLY APPEND
            lastTextBlock.Text += lastTextBlockString;
            Output.Text += _tmpResultString + "\r\n";

            _tmpResultString.Clear();

            if (endLoop) 
            {
                TextBox input = new TextBox();
                input.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkRed;
                input.KeyUp += input_KeyUp; // further stuff

                InteractiveWindow.Children.Add(input);
                return; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're familiar with `BackgroundWorker`, then there's a pretty straightforward translation to the `async` world:

1. Replace each `BackgroundWorker` instance with a single `Task.Run` call.
2. Replace the `ProgressChanged` event handler with a [`Progress<T>` (described on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).
3. Replace the `RunWorkerCompleted` event with code after the `await Task.Run(...)`.

Your code looks like it's starting a separate `Task.Run` within a `while` loop. If the code in each `Task.Run` executes very quickly, then this will not give your UI the opportunity to be responsive. Consider moving the `while` loop within the `Task.Run` delegate and using `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` for progress updates.

Comment: The task takes up to 10 seconds to run. Would you still suggest to go with the progress route ? hmm well, in that 10 seconds the loop is done about 100 times.

Comment: If the task (not the while loop as a whole) takes 10 seconds, then your UI should certainly be responsive. Try creating and posting a minimal repro.

Comment: yeah , the 10 seconds is for the whole while loop, and it loops about 100 times

Comment: If each `Task.Run` took 100ms to execute, that's plenty of time for a responsive UI. See what you can do to create a minimal repro; something that we can run and observe the behavior of.

Comment: Ok, so while the long tasks run, I found out that if I click on things very very fast the whole time the tasks run, some on the clicks are sucessfully done, but with a delay.

Comment: Well well well, thinking of it, it starts to make sense, since the long task is in the other thread, it means I'm rarely in the while that is in the UI thread, which means the UI is responsive only the time the text is added to the screen and then back to non responsive for about half a second each time. But if I put the whole while in the await, I loose the UI responsiveness in the loop.

Comment: If I add a sleep of 30 ms at the end of my task.run, the ui gets responsive and my object events are working. But the sleeps seems to make it much slower than 30 ms.